# Outputting mySQL Result with data from one column grouped into a single cell

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL query:

```
SELECT work.ID AS workID
      ,team.ID AS team_ID
      ,team.name AS teamName
  FROM work
  LEFT OUTER JOIN team_work ON team_work.work_ID = work.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN team ON team_work.team_ID = team.ID
```

that returns the following sample result:

```
workID   team_ID   teamName
1        10         Support
2        20         Dev
2        10         Support
3        30         Admin
4        40         Research
```

And I want to output it to the screen in a table format so that there is a row per workID, and column that has a list of team names. Something like:

```
WORK ID  |   TEAM NAME
-------------------------

1        |    Support

2        |    Dev
         |    Support

3        |    Admin

4        |    Research
```

I know a query in a query is not the right way (even though it is the easiest). I have seen some stuff on nested arrays but as a newbie I am not really clear on how to do it.

Anyone want to devote some time to talking me off the ledge?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT work.ID AS workID
      ,group_concat(teamName) AS teamName
FROM work
LEFT OUTER JOIN team_work ON team_work.work_ID = work.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN team ON team_work.team_ID = team.ID
group by work.ID
```